# install react-native-onesignal and let receive notifications even when the app is closed

Tags: react-native, onesignal

I followed this guide to install react-native-onesignal in a my project (React native SDK):

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup

When the app is opened, I receive the notifications.

The problem is that I do not receive notification when my app is closed. I am reading docs from many days but I still couldn't figure out howto do it.

I have another question:
Do I need also to follow the doc about Android SDK? Or the first one I followed is enough?